# Service Stack Intercept All Http To Service

Tags: c#, .net, http, servicestack

Is there a way to intercept all http requests that hit your services?

Example:

request for `http://host/Account/Create` get captured at a single place and redirected to correct service.

Request for `http://host/Account/Delete/1` get captured at a single place and redirected to correct service.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the [Order of Operations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations) for ServiceStack if you want specific detail on how filters function.

A `PreRequestFilter` is likely what you want, if you just want to filter every request via something like `Request.PathInfo`.

`PreRequestFilter` will fire for every request, but your DTO wont yet have been deserialized.  See example usage here in ServiceStack's own [RequestLogsFeature.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/1c73f0d5e3ab555d5c98bfbf19347f89cc5cde20/src/ServiceStack/RequestLogsFeature.cs#L92)

For my scenario, I use `RequestFilters` so I am able to make the decision based around `requestDto.GetType()` Type first, then fall back to `httpReq.PathInfo` if needed.  However, this will only fire for REST requests.

I do something like this in my AppHost class:

```
this.RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) =>
{
    if (AppConfig.RequireSsl) 
        new RequireSslAttribute().Execute(httpReq, httpResp, requestDto);

    // Force authentication if the request is not explicitly made public
    if (!AppConfig.IsPublic(httpReq, requestDto.GetType()))
        new AuthenticateAttribute().Execute(httpReq, httpResp, requestDto);
});
```